# Simultaneous text editing with Ajax?

Tags: javascript

I am using a text editor called TinyMCE. What I'd like to do is set up a way where two or more users can edit the same blog at the same time. If one user updates a portion of the blog, this should update for all users. The simplest approach in building a system like this is to just set up an Ajax query that will update for all users every second. This will create many calls to the database and possibly slow down performance. Is there a better way to accomplish something like this?

Currently, my database is very small. Less than 10 records. It will be less than that for a long time (> 1 year).

Comment: I have no clear idea but just sharing my small thought, can it be done without calling database for each user event for change? Instead, call database after a while to affect the last modified updates, in the meantime keeping those data somewhere which is fast enough than db calls like redis?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called websockets.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Assuming you are using PHP, this can probably help you : https://github.com/matejbasic/PHPWebSocket-TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

First idea, that requires no additional software - WebSockets. It will keep your traffic low.

Second idea is about data storage - Redis is better for real-time operations.
This solution uses ehterpad-lite with Redis: https://discourse.bigdinosaur.org/t/node-js-redis-and-etherpad-lite-bigdinosaur-blog/645